# PhpStorm ExpectedValues/expectedArguments array auto-complete

Tags: php, phpstorm

Is it possible to use the ExpectedValues trait or the expectedArgument() meta directive to hint the possible values in an array?

My use-case is a function that accepts either an array or a string:

```php
function check(array|string $checkable): bool
{
    if (!is_array($checkable)) {
        $checkable = [$checkable];
    }

    foreach ($checkable as $item) {
        if (!in_array($item, ['value1', 'value2', 'value anything'])) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here I wanted PhpStorm to auto-complete with the values in the array (`['value1', 'value2', 'value anything']`) when I use the function, both when passing an array of values and a value directly.

For just a single value this is already possible using #[ExpectedValues()] or [expectedArguments()](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html#expected-arguments).

```php
function check(
    #[ExpectedValues(values: ['value1', 'value2', 'value anything'])] array|string $checkable
): bool
```

But when passing an array it does nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible (an array with certain *values* only). You can define an **array shape** (array keys) with [PHPStan like PHPDoc](https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types#array-shapes) (that PhpStorm supports).. but I'm not sure about actual values (esp from a limited set -- the real-usage case?). Maybe Enums can be used instead here somehow (if it's a fixed set ofc)?

Comment: Actually -- `value-of<Type::ARRAY_CONST>` -- https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdoc-types#key-and-value-types-of-arrays-and-iterables --- try and see if PhpStorm supports this in full (both recognizing the stuff and in code completion -- the later might not be the case)

Comment: @LazyOne PhpStorm doesn't seem to support it at all sadly :/

Comment: PhpStorm supports the syntax and completion ... but for a single value parameter (just like `[ExpectedValues()]` or `expectedArguments()`) -- check this comment  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-60183#focus=Change-27-6393716.0-0 . NOTE: the support is provided by the bundled Pslam plugin. It must be enabled even if you do not use the actual Pslam -- it's about the IDE side of things for this syntax.

Comment: In either case, that likely be not enough for your `array()` needs. If you get no better suggestions here, I suggest you file a Feature request ticket to PhpStorm at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=WI and see what they have to say.

Comment: @LazyOne Yes, I was planning on doing that if it wasn't possible. Thank you very much though!